# How to interpret error (Win32) 0x3e5 (997) - Overlapped I/O operation is in progress in windows dump?

Tags: winapi, windbg, dump, sqldatareader

I have a postmortem windows dump file I need to analyze.  The process is stuck on .Net SqlDataReader reading values from SQL server over network.  There are no deadlocks found using !dlk or !syncblk.  I can see that it is making really slow progress internally and fetching rows.  The list it is building is expanding.  When I do !gle, I found this error.

0:009> !gle

LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0x3e5 (997) - Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000034 - Object Name not found.

Running !teb gives this output.

0:009> !teb

TEB at 000007ffffee4000

```
ExceptionList:        0000000000000000
StackBase:            000000001a800000
StackLimit:           000000001a7f9000
SubSystemTib:         0000000000000000
FiberData:            0000000000001e00
ArbitraryUserPointer: 0000000000000000
Self:                 000007ffffee4000
EnvironmentPointer:   0000000000000000
ClientId:             000000000000091c . 00000000000043bc
RpcHandle:            0000000000000000
Tls Storage:          000000001a8927e0
PEB Address:          000007fffffdc000
LastErrorValue:       997
LastStatusValue:      c0000034
Count Owned Locks:    0
HardErrorMode:        0
```

Could this be the root cause of this issue?  Can someone throw some light regarding this Win32 error and how to resolve this?

Comment: Error code 997 is normal when using overlapped (i.e., asynchronous) I/O.  I believe "Object Name not found" is also something that can occur during normal operation, it just means the program checked for the existence of some object (and the answer was that the object didn't exist).  Neither are likely to be relevant to your problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you verified, that your mini dump actually does contain information pertaining to the issue you are investigating? And what is the issue anyway?

Comment: Yes, the dump has the required information I believe.  The dumps were collected exactly at the time when the process becomes really slow and things are stuck.  Multiple dumps at regular interval have been taken.  The issue is .Net SqlDataReader takes lot of time in some SNI call. No deadlock is found though.

Comment: @murtazat, did you find the cause of the problem? It looks like I ran into a very similar problem.